# dynamic web api odata metadata additional properties

Tags: dynamic, asp.net-web-api, annotations, odata, data-annotations

In web `api odata` that uses `v4 protocol`, how to add additional attributes?

fully dynamic, no entity framework, no reflection providers,
   metadata is dynamically generated when url is called.

Edit
Web Api Request url:
http://locahost/Service1/EntitySet1

Actual json output:

```
{"@odata.context":"some url", value:[{"id":1}]}
```

Expected json response:

```
{"@odata.context":"some url", value:[{"id":1}], "ExtraCustomAttribute": "custom value"}
```

How to add this custom attribute in response `web api odata v4 json`?

In both metadata call (`edmx` response) and instance payload call (`json` response)).

Comment: Is your question is really unclear

Comment: i'm trying to add a property to the metadata.  did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

In OData v4 there are at least two options to implement that behavior: an open type,  Instance Annotations. It's depends on your requirements or design decisions.

The open type was added as a stuctured type that contains dynamic properties, in addition to any properties that are declared in the type definition. Open types let you add flexibility to your data models.

This tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4

shows how to use open types in ASP.NET Web API OData.

Instance Annotations are described here:
docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-os.html#_Toc372793088

In your case try to declare you entity as:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataModelBuilder();

ComplexTypeConfiguration<YourEntity> pressType = builder.ComplexType<YourEntity>();
// ...
pressType.HasDynamicProperties(c => c.ExtraCustomAttribute);
// public IDictionary<string, object> ExtraCustomAttribute{ get; set; }
```

and in get action method generate entity as you wish.
Another option is available to get control over entry serialization, check here

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OData%20formatter%20extensibility